# Cancel an Ajax call while calling the same function

Tags: php, ajax

I have a function:

```
function modifydata(what) {
    $.post(somepage.php+"?url="+replacedurl+"&userDesc="+userdesc+"&submitType="+what, {

    }, function(response){
        alert(response)
    });
}
```

I call the same function on two links link1, link2.

When the user clicks on link1 and the ajax is still processing, and if the user clicks link2 at the same time which calls the same function but with different values I'd like to shut the first processing to avoid load issues. Can it be possible without having the create the same function with a different name? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the previous XHR in a static variable, and abort if the value isn't null and then set to null when the XHR is done.